# Changing source of HTML5 Audio player from another page

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

I want to change the source of html5 audio player from other pages, and wanted to play it Please help

I have set up html5 audio player on a page1 with Jquery which can change the source of audio player

page1:

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function audplay(sourceUrl) {
       var player = document.getElementById('Audio1');


      $("#Audio1").attr("src",sourceUrl);
      $("#Audio1").trigger('play');
 }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<audio id="Audio1" controls="controls"     src="../mp3/test2.mp3"
type="audio/mp3" style="width:260px;" >   </audio>
```

Now i want to fire audplay(src) from page2
here's what i tried but it doesn't work

Page2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function winopen(xxx){

        $("#result").load("j-amma-tit1.htm", audplay(xxx));
</script>
```

and page2 HTML:

```
<a id="result" href=""></a>

    <area href="javascript:winopen('sound/1-1Layer-3.wav')" shape="rect" coords="19,6,425,47">
```

Comment: And what is "other pages", if it's a new window opened by the current page you have access to `window.opener`, otherwise HTML is stateless, and you can't access other pages in other browser tabs, even if they are from the same site.

Comment: @adeneo thank you for reply, Actually they both are on same page, its Frames stuff.. Like Page 1 is the side navigation bar but the content is page2 they both are different .html but are mapped i guess

Comment: Frames was pretty much deprecated ten years ago, and noone uses that anymore ?

Comment: but still any help will be much appreciated ..